# Facebook Hacker IP address

Tags: facebook

okay, so someone has been hacking my facebook and posting bad photos and i just got the ip address by downloading facebook info archive, but now, what can i do with it?? i thought of blocking but i don't know how to do this and also it is dynamic ip that can change i thought of finding the location but i tried this on my ip first to see the result it got me in a totally different place in another country, so now i have the ip but dunno what to do with it is there a way to know a facebook user account with this ip he is logging in with?? That may help a bit. and thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: A question suitable for Facebook help, perhaps (but not here).

Comment: You should change your password asap if you still have access to your account! And, have a look at https://www.facebook.com/help/148233965247823

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best venue for your question, but I would suggest getting in touch with FB customer service.  Not much you can do with an IP address yourself.